# Can someone explain this if statement for me?

Tags: if-statement

I'm new to programming, can someone take two minutes to explain this statement for me? how can I write it like this :
if (condition) {...} else {...}

```
if (myFunction(i == 8? (j + 1): j, (j + 1) % 9))
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is called with two arguments. First one uses a ternary operator to check if `i` (the index) is `8`; if so, increment `j`, else leave `j` as is.

Second argument increments `j` by `1`, it uses primary expression operator around `j+1` because arithmetic `+` has lower precedence than modulus (`%`) http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html. If `j` is `1` and we increment by `1`, then `2 % 9` is `2`, since the modulo operation returns the remainder. This assumes C style syntax.

```
int arg1 = i == 8 ? (j + 1) : j;
int arg2 = (j + 1) % 9;

if (myFunction(arg1,arg2))
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I think I'll need more of these tricks in my future codes :)

Comment: the `else { return false;}` part is not correct, it does not follow from the original code